# Passing model data from view to controller is resulting in an error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4.

I am receiving the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 47:@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id = Model.RestaurantId })
```

Here is my view that is causing the error (please see the last couple of lines):

```
@model OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Review</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id = Model.RestaurantId })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is my controller action that is being called when the Back To List link is clicked:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="id")]int restaurantId)
{
    var restaurant = _db.Restaurants.Find(restaurantId);
    if (restaurant != null) {
        return View(restaurant);
    }
    return HttpNotFound(); 
}
```

And here is the RestaurantReview model that is being strongly-typed in the view:

```
public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are showing the `Create` view, and the `Index` controller. Check if in the `Create` controller you are passing the `Model`, or check if it needs model.